# Thymeleaf display a table with dynamic amount of columns

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im working on a spring boot application using thymeleaf as my template engine. I have this case where I need to display a  that can vary in the amount of columns. This is what I have so far:

```
<table class="table table-hover" th:if="${d.hasRecords()}">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th:block th:eacth="h : ${d.header}">
                <th th:colspan="${d.header.length}" th:text="${h}">Header Field</th>
            </th:block>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="record : ${d.records}">
            <th:block th:each="field : ${record}">
                <td th:text="${field}">Dataset Field</td>
            </th:block>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `header` variable is a standard String[] array while the `records` object is a List of string arrays. The table displays the body of the table but not the header. The only difference (as far as I can see) is that the body is a nested loop while the header is not. Can someone help explain to me why the header won't show up. And no the header array is not empty or `null`

Comment: `th:eacth`, misspell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @holmis83 mentioned it was a misspell. Embarassing? yes